# DataSource leaves sleeping connections

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, datasource, jdbctemplate

I'm using Spring and have setup a DataSource bean:

```
@Bean DataSource getDataSource(){
    MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
    return ds;
}
```

I'm able to inject this DataSource object using Spring's `@Autowired` annotation and perform operations on the database. I'm running against a test instance of a MySQL server (with a connection limit of 150) and reached that limit within a few minutes. I checked on the number of connections, and the majority of the 150 connections are sleeping.

To decrease the number of sleeping connections, I've tried the following, but none were successful:

1) Instead of calling `dataSource.getConnection()` in each of my DAO's methods, I instead `@Autowired` a method called `setDataSource(DataSource ds)` in which I saved a reference to the Connection. My thinking was that instead of calling the `dataSource.getConnection()` each time, the particular instance of the DAO would use one connection instead. Doing all this worked fine, and it decreased the number of sleeping connections, but not by much.

2) I manually called the `close()` method on the `Connection` object. After doing so, the next time I made use of the dataSource (in any DAO), Spring threw an error indicating that the connection was already closed. (I'm assuming Spring *does not* re-instantiate `@Beans`?)

3) I modified the MySQL configuration file and set the wait_timeout variable to a few minutes. After the sleeping connections were cleaned up however, I received an error from Spring similar to that seen in #2 (`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.` and `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`)

Before I attempt to rewrite all my DAO operations to use JdbcTemplate instead of plain-old Java SQL prepared statements, I figured I'd ask here and see if there was a simple solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You should really be using a connection pool. And in the case of Spring, it's usually better to use higher-level constructs such as `JdbcTemplate` or Spring Data repositories.

Comment: @chrylis, I looked into JdbcTemplate, but from my initial impressions it looks to be a little heavy weight for what I'm trying to accomplish. Plus, I'm currently in the position to leverage existing Java Prepared Statements. Do you suggest any class in particular that I should look into regarding connection pooling?